# Speech to Text SWIFT

Tags: swift, machine-learning, speech-to-text, speech

I have the following code:

```
func createStringFromAudio () {
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization {_ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch SFSpeechRecognizer.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorized :
                let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ConversionTest", withExtension: "mp3")!
                let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
                let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL)
                recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                    guard error == nil else { print("Error"); return}
                    guard let result = result else {print("No result"); return}
                    print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                }
                break
            default :
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my question:
1: How do I know when the file is done? Currently it continually updates the result print but doesn't notify me when the transcription is 100% completed. How do I know when the transcription is done and I can save the string for parsing?

2: It seems to cut off before finishing. Is there a time limit? Character limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the task to check its status, even cancell it. 
Actually, the transcribing process is not controlled by us and when the system think its finished, it's finished.

If you do need precise controls, use  a delegate:

`func recognitionTask(with request: SFSpeechRecognitionRequest, delegate: SFSpeechRecognitionTaskDelegate) -> SFSpeechRecognitionTask`

This may provide more informations during transcribing, at least it will let you know when it is finished.